# Webdriver - Click and delete all displyed elements

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

**Problem**

I have an application that allows users to add memos to a webpage.  I need to be able to find all the memos and delete them from the page.  Problem is, I can never be sure of how many memos will be on the page and what it's ID will be.  Each "memo" is given a unique ID and it's dependent on how many memos are on the page.  e.g if there are three memos on the page then I will have three memos with ID's "memo01, memo02, memo03" etc.

What I do now is just search for 5 memos (I'm assuming there will be never any more than five) so I search for elements by ID containing "memo01, memo02, memo03" up to 5.  I then delete them in turn - This works.  I know this isn't ideal or particularly efficient, particularly now, when I have a case whereby I have 10 notes on the page

**Ideal Solution:**

What I have come up with is to find all ID's that contain "note" like so:

```
driver.Findelements(By.XPath("//*[contains(@id, 'note')]"));
```

I don't care to find a particular note.  I just need to find them all and delete them.  Trouble is, the xpath locator above also gets a handle on other elements I'm not interested in.  i.e they are in the DOM but not displayed on the page.

What I need is to loop around all elements containing "x" that are actually displayed (.displayed) on the page.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure notes aren't of the same (or a select few) element types? Also could they have a common parent tag that would help selecting them? Last, to check if the element is displayed I believe webdriver has a `webElement.isDisplayed()` method

Comment: Can you share HTML code?

Comment: If there's a REST API for creating these memos, there may be one for deleting them too. If so, use that before running your interactive test so you can run clean. It'll be quicker and more reliable than having to explicitly search for and delete them.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this :

```
// The selector insid CssSelector is to find all input's ID that contains "memo"
ICollection<IWebElement> listMemo = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("input[id*='memo']"));
               foreach (var item in listMemo)
                {
                    item.Displayed = false;
                }
```